# What is the value of default timeout for Outlook send/receive email?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

What is the value of default timeout for Outlook 2013 send/receive email? Or, maybe, Outlook use some different strategic for sending/receiving emails than simple timeout?

**Updated:** I am using Exchange account on LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of Outlook account do you use. For example, for POP3 and IMAP accounts you can configure the timeout in account settings, Advanced tab: Server Timeouts.

For Exchange accounts it depends on your connection type and server settings. You can't really do anything here, no way to figure timeout values.

Comment: Has updated my question.

Comment: So, for Exchange account I cannot figure exact value of timeout?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, you can't.